# Does WSO2 Identity Manager support multi-tenancy?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Does WSO2 Identity Manager support multi-tenancy?

requirements:

- an LDAP instance containing tenants (tenant admin accounts)
- Each tenant should be able to link multiple external directories and/or use an internal ApacheDS instance. For each tenant it should be possible to get a unified view over all the per-tenant configured directories (i.e: virtual directory / federation functionality)
- Would it be possible (for efficiency reasons) to securely host accounts of multiple tenants on the same internal ApacheDS instance? (which gets scaled when needed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. WSO2 Identity Server supports multi-tenancy out of the box.

Tenant admin details are by default saved to an internal H2 database which is configurable to point to an external database also, which can then be scaled.

The tenants can have there own multiple directories set up and these configurations can be dynamically configured via Management Console.

This post may help you,
http://pushpalankajaya.blogspot.com/2013/09/implemention-of-support-for-mutiple.html